# BindingContext always null

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have the following xaml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProj.Places"
             Title="Grid Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"
           Placeholder="Enter value..."
           TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged"
           SearchCommand="{Binding SearchButtonPressed}"
           SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference searchBar}, Path=Text}"/>
            <Label x:Name="LabelTextPress" Text="{Binding LabelTextPress}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Then the associated xaml.cs -

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Places : ContentPage
    {
        public Places()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var viewModel = BindingContext as Places;
            viewModel.LabelTextPress.Text = args.NewTextValue;
        }
    }
```

I can step into `Handle_TextChanged` just fine when using the searchbar, however my issue is I am unable to update the `LabelTextPress` because the binding isn't working.

`var viewModel = BindingContext as Places;` is always null, where am I going wrong with the binding of this?

Comment: Where do you set the `BindingContext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BindingContext` property will return `null` until you actually set it to something. You can for example do this in the constructor of the `ContentPage`:

```
public Places()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new YourViewModel();
}
```

The `SearchButtonPressed` property that you bind to in the XAML markup is supposed to be a property of the object (`YourViewModel`) that you set the `BindingContext` property to for the binding to work.

If you expect `BindingContext as Places` to return anything else than `null`, you should set the `BindingContext` to a `Places` instance, e.g.:

```
BindingContext = this;
```

Comment: hooray! Correct sir thank you, so I did - 

LabelTextPress.BindingContext = this;
LabelTextPress.Text = args.NewTextValue;